# VBA how do I edit cell contents based on contents of two other cells in same row

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a macro for cleaning up a csv sheet that contains product sales information including the shipping method that needs to be used. There are about 10 of our products that cannot be sent via our usual shipping methods and I need to overwrite the shipping method that is assigned to orders that contain these products.

- Column A is order numbers
- Column B is the product purchased
- Column C is the shipping method

If someone purchases multiple products in one order the order number is duplicated in the next row, the shipping method only displays in the first row with that order number and each consecutive product purchased in the same order just adds a new row with the product name in column B

I need to use VBA to check for a list of 10 or so specific products in column B and update the shipping method for the whole order (the upper most cell in column C that has the same value in cell A) if it contains one of these 10 products.

I think it needs to do something like this:

1. look at column B and search for a string of text
2. if cell matches the search criteria look at the value in column A in the same row
3. find the first instance of this value in Column A
4. replace the contents in Column B in the same row with the new shipping method

I would need this in a loop so that it does it for each instance of the search string in column B in the spreadsheet.

I hope this question is clear, I have searched SO and can't find an answer to this question. Any help or alternative fixes are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following code, given the setup and result in the following screenshots:

```
Sub test()

Dim pRange As Range
Dim nShip As Range

Set pRange = Range("E2")
pRange.Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

Range("B2").Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Value Then

Set nShip = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

End If

If ActiveCell.Value = pRange.Value Then

nShip.Value = pRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Wend

Set pRange = pRange.Offset(1, 0)
pRange.Select

Wend

End Sub
```

Starting List:

[image]

Result after macro:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this from what I can see it will do what I need it to - however there is the one problem that this iterates through every row X the number of products that I need to check.

This means that if I have say 1000 rows and 10 products it selects 10 000 cells, one by one.

As a result this macro takes a very long time to run, I wander if there is a more efficient way of searching the product purchased column for any items that are in the products to search column?

Comment: Also I have thought that one way that this could be chopped down is if it was not looking for an exact match of products. For example if I have products to search as Chair and TV then it will treat 'Chair - large' and 'Tv -42 inch' in the product purchased list as a match. I don't know how do to this?

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise how much time was saved by having screen updating off while this was running! Much faster when it doesn't have to worry about showing me everything!